# Lambda one container per invocation vs ECS thousands of invitations per container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Is it correct that AWS Lambda will execute only one request on each container at a time? Concurrency allocates separate containers for each request?

An single ECS container can process hundreds or thousands of concurrent requests though.

Why can't a single Lambda container process multiple invocations at once? Or am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct. Lambda containers can only process one request at a time. A container can be reused for another request, but only after the current request is done. Both Fargate and Lambda use [Firecracker](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/firecracker-lightweight-virtualization-for-serverless-computing/) internally, but Lambda is optimized for short term containers that can be provisioned faster.

From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-concurrency.html):

> Concurrency is the number of in-flight requests your AWS Lambda function is handling at the same time. **For each concurrent request, Lambda provisions a separate instance of your execution environment**. As your functions receive more requests, Lambda automatically handles scaling the number of execution environments until you reach your account's concurrency limit. By default, Lambda provides your account with a total concurrency limit of 1,000 across all functions in a region. To support your specific account needs, you can request a quota increase and configure function-level concurrency controls so that your critical functions don't experience throttling.

> When Lambda finishes processing the first request, this execution environment can then process additional requests for the same function. For subsequent requests, Lambda doesn't need to re-initialize the environment.
> [image: Chart of multiple concurrent requests and their assignment to different execution environments]